# Help with OpenCV cvInitUndistortRectifyMap and a single camera

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I'm trying to create a map that will undistort and rectify
a single camera.
Right now I'm doing this in two separate operations.

I've tried making a map with cvInitUndistortRectifyMap,
but I'm getting weird results.
Does anyone have an example how to do this ?
What should I give cvInitUndistortRectifyMap as "new camera matrix"
if I have just one camera ?

Thanks,
SW

Comment: Please show what you have done (source), what you expected it to do (input image and explanation), and what was different from your expectation (output image or result).

Comment: Right now I'm doing cvRemap to get an undistorted image, and then I do cvWarpPerspective to rectify it (user selected 4 corners on the undistorted image which are "expanded" to fit the whole image). This works fine but is too slow, when I tried making a map with cvInitUndistortRectifyMap all I get is a black image.

Comment: Posting source helps people to reproduce the problem you're having.  If you don't post source, the only way for someone to reproduce the problem is to write source from scratch.  For most people (e.g. me) doing this is **too much of a bother**.  If you post your source, I will be happy to have a look at it and dig around for the problem, and I'm sure other people would, too.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the source is complex, and dependent on several external resources. You will not be able to reproduce the problem easily. I'm just looking for someone that used cvInitUndistortRectifyMap. So far, I can't find any mention of anyone using this with one camera.

Comment: You may want to try the openCV mailing list -- you might get lucky.  http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/join

Answer (score 1):

For a single camera case `newCameraMatrix = cameraMatrix` unless you want to make the new image look like it was taken with a camera with different focal length.  You might want to center the image nonetheless.

The important input matrix is `distCoeffs` (correct distortion) and `R` (rectify).

Also, you can use `GetOptimalNewCameraMatrix` to calculate `newCameraMatrix`, but it really isn't necessary.